# How to structure app with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web-applications, frontend

I am trying to learn Angular JS and use it in my web app project and am looking for some guidance as well as answers to specific angular js questions. Tech stack I am using is MySQL db, Java w/ Spring Framework, HTML/CSS/Bootstrap/JS, etc..

The purpose of the app is basically a "social media craigslist" where it will have: 
1. User accounts
2. Ability to create a "newsfeed-esque" post (one "view")
3. Ability to create a sale post  (separate "view")
4. A view for an "inventory"
5. A view for a "wishlist"
etc.. 
(note: Items 2-5 are accessed via a nav bar of sorts that sits on the left side of my page and the idea was to have the main section of the page switch the content based on what nav item you clicked.. more later..)

What I was doing was writing a bunch of Javscript code to make calls to my web services (grabbing static content to populate drop downs, sending user login info for logging in, etc..) and the < script > tags were growing and all of this was living in my index.html page and I thought it might make more sense to use something like Angular JS and structure it a bit differently and "modularize" the code so it wasn't a giant mess in index page.  I was also doing some manual .hide() and .show() JS stuff so I thought that it also might make more sense to switch out the content using something like AngularJS instead of having maximum ONE .show() active at once and then having to do as many .hide()'s as I would need to, to manually switch out the content. This is sounding like a SPA (single page app) right?

I have researched AngularJS StackOverflow posts and looked at w3schools and other helpful websites but am having trouble with how to structure this and use best practices not only with code efforts but organizational as well.

1) Am I correct in thinking Angular would make the hide and show of content easier?

2) I would like to make each "feature" of my website have its own controller and have Controller1.js, Controller2.js, etc.. but do I need to have a

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);   ...
```

line at the top of each controller or do I need something like a main controller with that in there only once and then a call to each controller from a main controller?  Or is this not even how I should go about it?  Thought process was again to modularize and avoid having one giant beastly file with all my JS logic in it.

3) I assume that I need to use the ng-route stuff (is this correct?) in order to do that hide and show of html content? (items 2-5 listed above)  But in what file should that live? a javascript controller file? index.html? other?

4) I read you can only have one ng-view per application.  Does that mean that you can only switch/change the content for ONE < div > / section of your web app, OR can you have multiple different divs being changed?

5) fyi - my current file structure is pretty much this.. is this how it should be?

```
-Java Resources (java code)
...
-WebContent
  -img
  -META-INF
  -resources
    -css (folder)
    -js (folder with js files - controllers)
  -WEB-INF
    -lib (folder)
    -views (folder)
    -xx-servlet.xml
    -web.xml
  -index.html
-pom.xml
```

A lot of my questions are just because I am new to AngularJS and not seasoned in JS itself so am trying to better understand.  Thanks for any and all help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to use multiple views per app then you should use angular-ui-router module instead of angular-route module.

Now, we come to the file handling. So, for that you can make as much file as you can to define controllers, config, services and factories for the app. There are three ways of doing this.

The first one is putting `var app = angular.module("MyApp",[]);` in first file and defining controllers and services like `app.controller('ctrl', ControllerFunction)` in each of the other files below the first one. But, personally i don't prefer to use this way as you are exposing your app as a global variable here.

The second way is to create a main module in first file using `angular.module('MyApp',[])` and in other files you can get it and define controllers using `angular.module('MyApp').controller('ctrl', ControllerFunction)`. This is the safer way than the previous one.

The third way is to create a different module in each of the files and using all the modules in a single main module as dependencies. Like below

in one file

```
angular.module('Module1',[]).controller('ctrl1',CtrlFun1);
```

in another file

```
angular.module('Module2',[]).controller('ctrl2',CtrlFun2);
```

and in the main file, the main module, which is to be bootstraped

```
angular.module('MyApp',['Module1','Module2'])
```

This is the safest way to define services in different files. I personally advise this way of using multiple js files in single app. Because here you care not exposing a global variable or a single module, so anyone cannot inject some code using console easily.